# Remove any records with the same IDs (not removing only the duplicates)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Using C# .Net Core, I'm wanting to remove records/rows with duplicate IDs value, example:

```
ID    |  Value1
----------------
321   |  data_1
123   |  data_2
321   |  data_3
```

I want to completely remove BOTH rows with the same ID of 321, results would be:

```
ID    |  Value1
----------------
123   |  data_2
```

This is what I have:

```
IEnumerable<Table_Data> results = _context.Table_Datas.
  .GroupBy(s => new { s.ID })
  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
  .SelectMany(g => g)
  .ToList();

if (results != null) {
   _context.Table_Datas.RemoveRange(results);
}
```

I'm getting an error of

```
"InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Table_Data>()
.GroupBy(s => new { ID = s.ID })
.Where(x => x
.AsQueryable()
.Count() > 1)
.SelectMany(g => g)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."
```

Any help are greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you get object from "Table_Datas" and try to remove objects from "Accounts"?

Comment: Do you want to remove them locally on delete them in the table in the DB?

Comment: @JerzyGrzelec sorry updated

Comment: @Zee delete them in the table

Comment: `"InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression.."` and then? Exception details are going to tell us what is wrong with your query.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman added

Comment: @VictoriaLe `IEnumerable<Table_Data> results = _context.Table_Datas.
  .GroupBy(s => new { s.ID })
  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
  .SelectMany(g => g)
  .ToList();` this would load the entire table(or a big chunk of it) in to memory, are you sure you'll want to do that? You can easily accomplish this with a sql query

Comment: If you want to delete the duplicate records in the table, assuming you're using sql, you can execute this SQL command `Delete from Table_Datas where ID in
(
    Select ID from Table_Datas group by ID having count() > 1
)`.

Comment: @Zee I would post that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the records from a table which have duplicate records in the table, assuming you're using sql, you can execute this SQL command

```
Delete from Table_Datas where ID in (     
  Select ID from Table_Datas group by ID having count() > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`results` will per definition never be `null` when you call `.ToList()`. It will be an empty `List`. So, the check needs to be:

```
if (results.Count() > 0)
{
   _context.Accounts.RemoveRange(results);
}
```

Then, according to MS Docs, there is no `.RemoveRange` that accepts only 1 parameter so please include your custom method or from which library you're using this function. As you submitted the question, this should/would not compile.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?view=net-6.0

That said, you want to exclude all your results from the original list. You can do that like this:

```
if (results.Count() > 0)
{
  _context.Table_Datas = _context.Table_Datas
    .Except(results)
    .ToList(); // assuming _context.Table_Datas is a list
}
```

PS: In your examples and coding, please follow C# coding conventions if your team/project permits it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions. C# methods put the bracket on the next line.

EDIT: In response to your error message, try changing your LINQ to;

```
_context.Table_Datas.
  .GroupBy(s => s.ID)
  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
  .SelectMany(g => g)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I like the direction where you're going with this and tested it, however, I'm getting the same error, I've posted the full error message above on my post if you'd like to check it out

Comment: It's probably [DbContext.RemoveRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.removerange?view=efcore-6.0) from ef-core (which can take 1 parameter), not the `List<T>.RemoveRange` you linked too

Comment: @VictoriaLe Your code is crashing on the GroupBy, not on the empty result that I expected earlier. I added a possible rewrite of the GroupBy.